# Example code wanted for Zend_Form_Element_File in conjunction with Zend_ProgressBar_Adapter_JsPush

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload

I've got a Zend_Form with a Zend_Form_Element_File item which I'm trying to provide a "upload progress" report to the user utilising Zend_ProgressBar_Adapter_JsPush. However, I can't figure out how to do this and I was wondering if anybody with more experience of this section of the Zend Framework could help.

The examples on Zend's framework ( http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.progressbar.introduction.html , http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.introduction.html and http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.file ) all make mention of each other, but I just cannot figure out how to tie them all together. Can somebody provide a short example of where/how to show the upload progress when using Zend_Form_Element_File?

(The server does have the uploadprogress installed).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about using Zend Form; not a big fan of it myself.

However this is a pretty easy way of showing upload progress:

http://swfupload.org/